# MySQL return no results from select * where varchar="" query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm having issue with my study project for creating database in MySQL.
I've imported data using LOAD to my created table from a CSV file. Now when I'm executing `select * from mytable` everything show up perfectly, but when I execute `select * from bi_jogging.routes as r where r.Creator_Email="jhenderson7c@bbb.org"`
I get nothing.

The email is there, I've tried different syntax options but it seems to be something else, I suspect something with the varchar format, I really have nothing in mind.

For other tables it works fine and others not.

Comment: You get nothing or an error?

Comment: Nothing, no error at all. just empty results. it obviously effects joins queries also, when joining on condition (r.mail=p.mail) also no results

Comment: for testing try `LIKE` operator in where clause, `r.Creator_Email LIKE '%jhenderson7c@bbb.org%';`.

Comment: the LIKE operator shows up the results, but I fear its not enough, the joins still won't show the results. its critical because we're creating data warehouse and it affects our manipulating on the data. I dont know whats wrong

Comment: Johnny, did you try to copy value from email field and past it to where clause ? I ask to be sure that there is no spelling mistake or other white spaces etc.

Comment: Tried that of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the query:

```
select * from bi_jogging.routes as r where r.Creator_Email like "%jhenderson7c@bbb.org%"
```

If like operator shows the result then there may be white spaces in the email, please double check..

For join try this:

```
select * from bi_jogging.routes as r join bi_jogging.buddies as b 
on b.Email like '%r.Creator_Email%'
```

Comment: LIKE operator works fine. but look at select * from bi_jogging.routes as r join bi_jogging.buddies as b on r.Creator_Email=b.Email, those have matches emails but no result.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for replying, I now understand that the problem is in the raw data from the CSV, but I have to insist on using the regular join with the "=" because I then perform joins on Talend software(for ETL process). Is there anyway to fix the data? I can't find any spaces or whatsoever

Comment: what was the issue in data ? any line spaces or what ?

Comment: Thats the thing, I dont find anything wrong with it.. each table was created from different CSV file, looking at the emails I see nothing unique. it all looks good both in the CSV's and the MySQL tables.

Comment: If I go into "Edit top 1000 rows" and delete an email and then type it again it works (Update operator), but looking at CSV can't find anything.. I know you can't find the problem for me so I thank you for the answer so far.

Comment: yes because there is difference of row field ending delimiter..
in some cases fields ended by \r\n and in some cases by \n

Comment: you need to update the data that you can do by using replace command and edit the last characters of your data.

Comment: Thanks!, is that a way to fix the tables? not by going and replacing each row?

Comment: you can use replace command and update that column for the whole table.. but it takes time is table is large.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work. Again check with same code.

select * from bi_jogging.routes as r where r.Creator_Email='jhenderson7c@bbb.org'

Answer (score 0):

I found spaces in the mysql tables after few emails, so I guess that was it. burned 8 hours on this one, thank you all. I could not find the spaces at the end of the mail by looking at it, I had to hit backspace to see that only after two hits the last char is deleted

this helped me : `UPDATE bi_jogging.results set Mail_Found = TRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(Mail_Found,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r',''));`

Answer (score 0):

if [`select * from mytable`] this works ,then try to copy the email from result and paste it in where clause.

There may be conflicts between quotes.

your  table entry contains quotes???
 check properly. i think you have quotes in your table entry,so when you try this,

```
select * from bi_jogging.routes as r where r.Creator_Email like "%jhenderson7c@bbb.org%"
```

'%' sign matches with any character and you will get the result.
Inside the table`jhenderson7c@bbb.org` and `"jhenderson7c@bbb.org"` are completely different.